# Update/Migration from VS10 to 11 with TFS10 in house

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

Situation:
- TFS2010 and VS2010 in house.

There is a VS11 coming in the pipe later this year (hopefully), can we keep using TFS2010 if we update our VS10 to VS11? Are there any complications with the relationship of TFS10 to VS11? I know we are going to have issues with updating the VS10 projects probably..

But on a more general level, is TFS10 compatible with VS11? And does anyone see any problems arising with upgrade?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything will be fine. You can use TFS2010 with VS11, you will have everything except the "my work" experience which requires TFS11.

You also will be able to open projects/solutions for VS10 with VS11 **without** any upgrade in order to have a mix of VS10 & VS11 in your team (finally!!!) See this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2012/03/28/round-tripping-with-visual-studio-11.aspx).

Comment: Oh wow! That sounds absolutely amazing. Thanks mate! Appreciated. This was definitely what I was looking for. Since we have no real reason to update our TFS10 to, well, anything for now. But the issue and the burning "need" is for VS10. Again, thanks for the reply.

Comment: Also worth noting that VS versions install side by side, they do not upgrade. So quite possible to run VS2010 and VS11 side by side (eg. for the project types – there are some – that don't round trip between the versions).